# Microsoft Azure App Service Managed Certificates: binding with and without "www"

Tags: azure-devops

I was able to create an App Service Managed Certificate for my Azure Web App with the domain [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), and binded it to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), but of course it still shows mydomain.com as insecure so I go back to "Create App Service Managed Certificate" to create another for mydomain.com but it says "A certificate has already been issued to this domain" so how do I secure mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, unless I'm missing something, it seems the App Service Managed Certificate cannot be bound to a naked domain, which makes no sense to me, why would anyone want a cert that protects [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) but not mydomain.com?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)